# If we put maxsize = 0 in Queue . What happens then and can we insert elements after this?

Tags: python, queue, stack, python-3.8

**Can we insert elements in the Queue if maxsize = 0 ?**
what Does this means:- 'A max size of zero ‘0’ means an infinite queue'?
If we will put maxsize= 0 how can it have  infinite queue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the documentation says *"the queue size is infinite"*, it doesn't mean that infinite memory has been allocated for the queue, nor that you somehow could add an infinite number of elements to it. This is of course not possible, as there are always finite memory constraints.

When you provide 0 to the constructor, the `Queue` implementation does not *itself* pose any limit on how many items you could add to the queue. It will dynamically allocate more memory as needed while items are being added to it. It will never "block" an insertion, as it would do in the case of a non-zero limit. The only constraint is available memory.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) says.

> Constructor for a FIFO queue. maxsize is an integer that sets the upperbound limit on the number of items that can be placed in the queue. Insertion will block once this size has been reached, until queue items are consumed. If maxsize is less than or equal to zero, the queue size is infinite.

If the question is "how can we have an infinite queue with max size 0" then the answer is simply convention. The writers of the queue package decided this was the value they'd use to indicate an infinite queue. I don't think (and am not aware) of any better explanation.

To answer the question more directly - the queue is indeed infinite:

```
>>> from queue import Queue
>>> queue = Queue(maxsize=0)

>>> for i in range(100000000):
...     queue.put(i)
```

Even though you can't really test "infinity" this code will run to the end of the range.